# AWS: Why is the bucket size on CloudWatch higher than when using S3 tools?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, amazon-cloudwatch

I use the awscli tools to verify the size of my buckets. First the S3 call (all files without versioning, just an ordinary upload):

`$ aws s3 ls s3://XXX --recursive --human-readable --summarize
(...)
Total Objects: 2
  Total Size: 82.5 GiB`

Then I used the CloudWatch metric:

`$ aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics --namespace "AWS/S3" --start-time 2015-08-29 --end-time 2015-08-31 --metric-name BucketSizeBytes --period 3600 --statistics Average --unit Bytes --dimensions Name=BucketName,Value=XXX Name=StorageType,Value=StandardStorage
{
   "Datapoints": [
      {
          "Timestamp": "2015-08-30T00:00:00Z", 
          "Average": 141012339184.0, 
          "Unit": "Bytes"
       },  (...)`

Now I am wondering why CloudWatch shows a much higher number than the S3 call. I couldn't find any hint from the documentation and therefore would be grateful if anybody could help.

(Same numbers are shown in the management console; about 82.5 GiB on the S3 console and 141,012,339,184 bytes on the CloudWatch console.)

Comment: Is versioning enabled on the bucket?  Is it possible that you have a large number of abandoned multipart upload operations?  (They never time out, and consume storage until you complete or abort them).

Comment: Versioning is disabled. Thanks for the hint conecerning the abandoned multipart uploads operations. I checked this and found some uploads that weren't completed.

Comment: And after aborting them I now get the same result for the usage. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question with: There were abandonend multipart uploads that were correctly counted in CloudWatch.

Comment: Mark your answer as the answer :)

Comment: Here is the link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html